# Magento 2 Resource Model not working

Tags: module, admin, magento2.2, di

**Di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Mageplaza_HelloWorld extension
 *                     NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 *                     This source file is subject to the Mageplaza License
 *                     that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 *                     It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 *                     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 *                     @category  Mageplaza
 *                     @package   Mageplaza_HelloWorld
 *                     @copyright Copyright (c) 2016
 *                     @license   https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="SunarcWarehouseGirdFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
                <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="SunarcWarehousePostGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">Sunarc\Warehouse\Model\ResourceModel\Warehouse\Collection</argument>
            <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SunarcWarehouseGirdFilterPool</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Sunarc\Warehouse\Model\ResourceModel\Warehouse\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_detail</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">warehouse_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Sunarc\Warehouse\Model\ResourceModel\Warehouse</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Sunarc\Warehouse\Model\ResourceModel\Warehouse\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>


layout/sunarc_warehouse_warehoue_listing.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Mageplaza_HelloWorld extension
 *                     NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 *                     This source file is subject to the Mageplaza License
 *                     that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 *                     It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 *                     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 *                     @category  Mageplaza
 *                     @package   Mageplaza_HelloWorld
 *                     @copyright Copyright (c) 2016
 *                     @license   https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Post</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">SunarcWarehousePostGridDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <!--<container name="listing_top">-->
        <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>-->
                <!--<item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>-->
            <!--</item>-->
        <!--</argument>-->
        <!--<bookmark name="bookmarks">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</bookmark>-->
        <!--<component name="columns_controls">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</component>-->
        <!--<exportButton name="export_button">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns.ids</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</exportButton>-->
        <!--<filterSearch name="fulltext">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing_data_source</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</filterSearch>-->
        <!--<filters name="listing_filters">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="templates" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="filters" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="select" xsi:type="array">-->
                                <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>-->
                                <!--<item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>-->
                            <!--</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="imports" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="visible" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
                <!--<item name="observers" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</filters>-->
        <!--<massaction name="listing_massaction">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns.ids</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
            <!--<action name="delete">-->
                <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="warehouse/warehouse/massDelete"/>-->
                        <!--<item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Posts</item>-->
                            <!--<item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected Posts?</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
            <!--<action name="edit">-->
                <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="callback" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns_editor</item>-->
                            <!--<item name="target" xsi:type="string">editSelected</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</argument>-->
            <!--</action>-->
        <!--</massaction>-->
        <!--<paging name="listing_paging">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns.ids</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</paging>-->
    <!--</container>-->
    <!--<columns name="sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns">-->
        <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
                <!--<item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns.ids</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="warehouse/warehouse/inlineEdit"/>-->
                        <!--<item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
                <!--<item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns_editor</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="params" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>-->
                            <!--<item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</item>-->
        <!--</argument>-->
        <!--<selectionsColumn name="ids">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</selectionsColumn>-->
        <!--<column name="entity_id">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</column>-->
        <!--<column name="warehouse_name">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="editor" xsi:type="array">-->
                        <!--<item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>-->
                        <!--<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">-->
                            <!--<item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
                        <!--</item>-->
                    <!--</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Warehouse Name</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</column>-->
        <!--<column name="status">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</item>-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</column>-->
        <!--<column name="created_time" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</column>-->
        <!--<column name="update_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Modified</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</column>-->
        <!--<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Sunarc\Warehouse\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\PostActions">-->
            <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                    <!--<item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>-->
                    <!--<item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>-->
                <!--</item>-->
            <!--</argument>-->
        <!--</actionsColumn>-->
    <!--</columns>-->
    <!--<container name="sticky">-->
        <!--<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">-->
            <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">-->
                <!--<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/sticky/sticky</item>-->
                <!--<item name="toolbarProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.listing_top</item>-->
                <!--<item name="listingProvider" xsi:type="string">sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing.sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_columns</item>-->
            <!--</item>-->
        <!--</argument>-->
    <!--</container>-->
</listing>

sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="menu">
            <action method="setActive">
                <argument name="itemId" xsi:type="string">Sunarc_Warehouse::warehouses</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="page.title">
            <action method="setTitleClass">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">complex</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sunarc_warehouse_warehouse_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: Please include more info about the issue

Comment: don't understood what is exact issue,Please explain in brief